# Vim macro from yanked text enters insert mode

Tags: vim, macros

I have the strangest problem with a macro created from yanked text. I have an access to another vim installation on Ubuntu (I use Gentoo) and this problem does not occur. What I need is help to find the reason of such a behaviour.

### First a case that works ok:

I start recording a macro with, let's say, `qr`.

I type exactly the following characters: `iasdas<ESC>q`

This macro should insert text `asdas` and exit insert mode. Running it with `@r` does exactly that.

### Second case:

Now I want to manually type my macro, yank it and run.

I enter in insert mode:

```
iasdas^[
```

Of course `^[` is inserted with `<Ctrl>+v, <ESC>`.

I yank it to a register `q`: `"qyy`.

Then I verify the content of `q` and it's exactly correct.

I run it with `@q` and what I get is most confusing. Text `asdas` is typed, vim is in **insert mode**(!) and the cursor is over the last `s`.

It means that actually what happened is `iasdas^[i` - otherwise the cursor would be **after** `s`. Changing `^[` to `jj`, which I have mapped to escape, didn't change anything.

I have an extremely complicated macro which I tried to edit by hand. Now I have to escape insert mode after macro, which is bad in so many ways...

As a workaround I've made a macro which contains `@q^[`, but it breaks behaviour of `@@`, so it's not a good solution.

This problem gave me a headache. I don't know where to start looking for a reason of this. I have just updated to Vim 7.4, the same behaviour was observed on my 7.3 with the exactly same configuration.

My .vimrc is pretty long with ~10 addons. Trying to remove each one of them is kinda lot of work, so I'd love to have a hint on any other way to trace it.

### Edit

With suggestion from I've tried to debug, running vim -V100vimlog filename and I get:

```
...
Calling shell to execute: "(printf "0x%X" $((0x4A307204 +0x4))) >/tmp/vWo43Tm/2 2>&1" 
Executing CursorMoved Auto commands for "*"
Executing TextChanged Auto commands for "*"
Executing CursorMoved Auto commands for "*"
Executing CursorMoved Auto commands for "*"
Executing CursorMoved Auto commands for "*"
Executing TextChanged Auto commands for "*"
Executing CursorMoved Auto commands for "*"
Executing CursorMoved Auto commands for "*"
Executing InsertEnter Auto commands for "*"-- INSERT --
...
```

Don't know why this InsertEnter fires though, can I get a more elaborate output?

Comment: I'd also venture that this is related to a mapping or an `:autocmd InsertLeave` event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the culprit.

The problem is with "yy".

Actually, I stated `Then I verify the content of q and it's exactly correct.` That not true. `yy` copied `^M` at the end of the line.

I've detected it thanks to @IngoKarkat and @Amit answer. Pasting a macro inside a command line showed this: `:iasdas^[^M`.

I don't know why it caused entering the insert mode. I don't have such a mapping for enter key, does it mean something else?

Most confusing, but fun to find. Thanks @Amit and @IngoKarkat for your answer, it was a good hint!

Of course, yanking without `^M` solved the case in a way.

Comment: Right:  use `y$` instead of `yy`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
:let @q='iasds^['
```

Comment: Yep, and you don't need to retype it, `'<C-r>q'` will insert it for you (then use the command-line history to recall and re-edit).

Comment: That was a good hint, both from Amit and @IngoKarkat, thank you. I've made an answer (although there are still some mysteries ;-))